# Gmail on Chrome Browser - Change on 2/19/2019

Tags: gmail, account-management

I use several Gmail accounts, and for years I've been able to access each inbox separately on my Android phone. A few days ago, Google in all it's top-down command non-wisdom changed this so I have only one inbox for two businesses and one non-profit.

All emails dumped into one inbox has created pandemonium for me. They appear to have removed any ability for the user to choose their preference for one or separate inboxes. Help! I'm about to pay for an email service, but... behold, they all seem to think a single inbox is great for everyone! Anyone know of any options to get separate inboxes again?

Answer (score 0):

- **you can still do so by adding a new person to your browser:**

[image]